# vue.v3@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`

Tags: vue.js, npm

i install bootstarp-vue " npm install bootstarp-vue " , i get a error When i run  the project .

```
λ npm run serve

> vue.v3@0.1.0 serve G:\vue\vue.v3
> vue-cli-service serve

'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue.v3@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue.v3@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-02T10_50_03_822Z-debug.log
```

I have tried " npm install " and nothing change 
--- i removed the node_module and run npm install and get this error

```
 λ npm install
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path G:\vue\vue.v3\node_modules\register-service-worker\npm-shrinkwrap.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'G:\vue\vue.v3\node_modules\register-service-worker\npm-shrinkwrap.json'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'G:\vue\vue.v3\node_modules\register-service-worker\npm-shrinkwrap.json'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'G:\vue\vue.v3\node_modules\register-service-worker\npm-shrinkwrap.json'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!     path: 'G:\\vue\\vue.v3\\node_modules\\register-service-worker\\npm-shrinkwrap.json'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'G:\\vue\\vue.v3\\node_modules\\register-service-worker\\npm-shrinkwrap.json'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'G:\\vue\\vue.v3\\node_modules\\register-service-worker\\npm-shrinkwrap.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'vue.v3'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-02T11_11_58_100Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you installed vue CLI globally ? ( npm install -g @vue/cli ) ( you can check which package have been installed globally by using the following command : npm list -g )

Comment: Of course i do that

Comment: ok :) and have you try to delete the node_module folder and run npm install to reinstall all dependencies. Also you can maybe edit your post with the content of your package.json

Comment: i removed the node_module an run npm install and get error

Comment: i edit my post and add the error

Comment: You seams to have some permission issue. Can you try to run you command prompt as administrator, and close everything to make sure nothing is already opened in a editor for example

Answer (score 0):

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hypermarket@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hypermarket@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**This happens when you remove a Dependency from package.js.**

**---->For example:** when i removed the **"eslint"** by `npm remove eslint` command , encountered this error.

**---->my solution is:** `npm install eslint`

> i found the my problem by compare "package.js" using git changes.