# npm run server throws error sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm trying to setup an existing vue project and getting this error

```
admin@kali:/media/veracrypt1/themeforest-LSerfC0M-skote-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/Admin$ npm run serve

> skote@0.1.0 serve /media/veracrypt1/themeforest-LSerfC0M-skote-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/Admin
> vue-cli-service serve

sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! skote@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the skote@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/admin/.npm/_logs/2020-01-22T19_13_27_378Z-debug.log
```

on windows I was able to resolve it by deleting the "node_modules" folder and reinstalling it but here in linux nothing works, deleting it or even reinstalling the dependencies.

Below is the contents of the error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'serve' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v10.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle skote@0.1.0~preserve: skote@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle skote@0.1.0~serve: skote@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle skote@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle skote@0.1.0~serve: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/media/veracrypt1/themeforest-LSerfC0M-skote-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/Admin/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
9 verbose lifecycle skote@0.1.0~serve: CWD: /media/veracrypt1/themeforest-LSerfC0M-skote-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/Admin
10 silly lifecycle skote@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 info lifecycle skote@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
12 verbose stack Error: skote@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
13 verbose pkgid skote@0.1.0
14 verbose cwd /media/veracrypt1/themeforest-LSerfC0M-skote-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/Admin
15 verbose Linux 5.3.0-kali2-amd64
16 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
17 verbose node v10.17.0
18 verbose npm  v6.13.4
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file sh
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error skote@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the skote@0.1.0 serve script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: this is a duplicate question.
[check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137405/vue-v30-1-0-serve-vue-cli-service-serve/61039648#61039648)

Answer (score 45):

Run:

```
npm i @vue/cli-service
```

That's because your dependence is not installed.

Answer (score 17):

Removing `node_modules` folder along with `package-lock.json` file and running fresh npm install worked for me.

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install
```

(Found solution here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2404#issuecomment-443397971)

#### NB

In case if moving to different/new OS environment - might also be that no vue-cli is installed, then install vue-cli as per instructions in the [official guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html).

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to `npm install` after `npm i @vue/cli`, especially if you have Typescript.

There may be additional Typescript libraries necessary after installing `@vue/cli`.

Comment: This is actually the reason behind m.f's answer working for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

- uninstall vue/cli with `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
- install vue/cli again with `npm install -g @vue/cli` (you may also try it with  sudo, like `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`)
- `vue`

Comment: I'm using kali linux and it seems it's not supported by some of the dependencies, it's looking for distro type: darwin.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem with your babel.config.js file.
Open it and chek out the path! In my case, the path was wrong!
This will solve your problem for 90%.

**At first it was...**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugins-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

And, I found my mistake in PLUGINS and changed it as you see below. It woked perfectly! It should be PLUGIN not PLUGINS. I think this mistake happened when I used refactor(rename).  In your case names can be different but if you find it. You will solve the problem!

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```