# Vue CLI errors trying to deploy vue app with docker

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, vuejs3

I have a VUE app I have been developing locally which I am trying to deploy to a remote server for testing.

My dev machine is running Arch with `Docker 20.10.17`

My VUE app has the following `Dev.Dockerfile` which is used to build it:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json /code/

RUN npm install --location=global @vue/cli

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

# serve application in development
CMD [ "yarn", "serve" ]
```

The relevant service in my `docker-compose.yml` is:

```yaml
frontend:
  build: 
    context: ./frontend
    dockerfile: dockerfiles/Dev.Dockerfile
  command: yarn serve
  stdin_open: true
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./frontend/:/code/
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

The VUE service is part of a larger set of services I am setting up with docker-compose.

This seems to be running fine on my local machine (Arch with the latest Docker).

When I try to deploy this to an Ubuntu 20.04 server, however, I run into issues.

The server is running Docker-compose `1.29.2` and Docker 20.17.1

The build goes fine, but when I try to run `docker-compose up` I get:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vue-cli-service serve
/bin/sh: vue-cli-service: not found
```

Reading elsewhere on stackoverflow about this issue, I tried installing:

```
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli-service
```

This changes the error to:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vue-cli-service serve
...
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'
```

I have also tried to explicitly install:

```
RUN npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env
RUN npm install @vue/cli-plugin-babel
```

The error remains the same.

This is not an issue on my local machine running Arch, only the remote machine running Ubuntu 20. How do I fix this?

MORE INFORMATION.

After experimenting with @amir's answer I have some more information.

On Arch, `Docker compose` is now a command in Docker and I have been using it without thinking about it. On the Ubuntu server that doesn't work and instead I am using the 'docker-compose' command. I "assumed" these were functionally the same but I think `docker-compose` is causing the failure.

If I build my `frontend` service manually with Docker and my `Dev.Dockerfile` and then run it with Docker it works perfectly. No warnings.

Building with `Docker-compose` works... but throws a number a warnings:

```
yarn add v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @vue/cli-service > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > apollo-server-core > subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > apollo-server-core > graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > graphql-tools > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @vue/cli > vue-codemod > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > apollo-server-core > apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > apollo-server-core > graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
warning @vue/cli > vue-codemod > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @vue/cli > vue-codemod > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
warning @vue/cli > vue-codemod > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > apollo-server-express > apollo-server-core > apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
```

So it isn't finding the yarn.lock file - which is there - and throwing a number of module errors.

Again, this does not occur on my Arch machine running 'Docker compose' but does on an Ubuntu 20.04 server running `docker-compose`

I did try adding a volume directly to the `node_module` directory as per @amir's answer but that did not work. I also tried changing the copy location for the Dockerfile as per that answer. No joy.

Ideas? I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After a lot of trial and error and lots of help from @Amir Jani I was able to fix it.

In case it helps anyone else. What was occuring is the node_module directory was being overwritten in the final image build. This is simmilar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds)

The fix was to add a volume to store the `node_module` directory. The syntax for the volume had to be absolute from the volume storing the code - since that's where my `node_module` was located.

Final Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```bash
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /code
COPY package*.json /code/
RUN yarn add global @vue/cli
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
CMD [ "yarn", "serve" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    ...
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/Dev.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/code/
      - /code/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it seems to work. Is mounting the node_modules bad for any reason?

I am still confused why this wasn't a problem on an Arch machine but was on Ubuntu 20. The versions of docker used were the same. If anyone could explain that it would be a big help

Answer (score 1):

Hi I fixed my own version with below dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.6-alpine3.14
WORKDIR /code
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add curl py-pip make g++
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
RUN yarn install
CMD yarn dev # or serve
```

I think there might be a problem in your copying `package.json` file line

```yaml
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    build:
      context: <Context>
      target: <TARGET>
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - <Location>:/code
      - <Location>/node_modules
```

Comment: This answer didn't fix things but it's helped find some other issues. I think the problem is docker compose. Building with Docker directly works...

Comment: do you delete the ```command: yarn serve``` and ```stdin: true``` there is no need for them

Comment: I did. No change.

Comment: would you add ```docker logs  <container name>```?

Comment: The logs just repeat the error: ```yarn run v1.22.19
$ vue-cli-service serve
/bin/sh: vue-cli-service: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.```

Comment: will you check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866945/npm-run-server-throws-error-sh-1-vue-cli-service-not-found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245838/discussion-between-amir-jani-and-tanbog).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in the Dockerfile:

`NODE_ENV=development npm run instal` and this might resolve vue-cli issue

Comment: Are these two separate commands? It's not clear from the formatting.