# How do i solve npm error “npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE”

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

When I try to run npm run serve for my vue live server I get this error, why is this?

```
error code ELIFECYCLE
error errno 1
error example@1.0.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
error Exit status 1
error Failed at the example@1.0.0 serve script.
error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039648/13126651  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873162/13126651 possible duplicate of these

Answer (score 1):

try this steps :

1. deleting "node_modules" directory in project

```sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

2. npm install to install dependencies

```sh
npm install
```

after that run your command .

I think that will resolve your issue .

Comment: this might be a dumb question  but can you run sudo on windows?

Comment: when you are  a windows user you can delete the node_modules using your GUI after that npm install and finally serve

Comment: oh, that makes sense hahaha and thanks so much!